# Z3 Build Error Using Visual Studio: fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'x86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'

Tags: visual-studio, z3

I tried to build Z3 on Win10 64 Professional using Visual Studio 2019.I followed the README instructions up and hit nmake in the "build" directory. After that, I got the following:

```
 cl  /Fez3.exe /nologo /MD shell\datalog_frontend.obj shell\dimacs_frontend.obj shell\drat_frontend.obj shell\gparams_register_modules.obj shell\install_tactic.obj shell\main.obj shell\mem_initializer.obj shell\opt_frontend.obj shell\smtlib_frontend.obj shell\z3_log_frontend.obj api\api.lib cmd_context\extra_cmds\extra_cmds.lib opt\opt.lib tactic\portfolio\portfolio.lib tactic\fpa\fpa_tactics.lib tactic\ufbv\ufbv_tactic.lib tactic\smtlogics\smtlogic_tactics.lib muz\fp\fp.lib muz\bmc\bmc.lib muz\ddnf\ddnf.lib muz\tab\tab.lib muz\clp\clp.lib muz\spacer\spacer.lib muz\rel\rel.lib muz\transforms\transforms.lib muz\dataflow\dataflow.lib muz\base\muz.lib tactic\fd_solver\fd_solver.lib sat\sat_solver\sat_solver.lib qe\qe.lib tactic\sls\sls_tactic.lib smt\tactic\smt_tactic.lib tactic\bv\bv_tactics.lib nlsat\tactic\nlsat_tactic.lib sat\tactic\sat_tactic.lib sat\smt\sat_smt.lib smt\smt.lib smt\proto_model\proto_model.lib math\subpaving\tactic\subpaving_tactic.lib solver\assertions\solver_assertions.lib tactic\arith\arith_tactics.lib tactic\core\core_tactics.lib ast\fpa\fpa.lib ackermannization\ackermannization.lib tactic\aig\aig_tactic.lib ast\pattern\pattern.lib parsers\smt2\smt2parser.lib cmd_context\cmd_context.lib solver\solver.lib qe\lite\qe_lite.lib qe\mbp\mbp.lib tactic\tactic.lib ast\simplifiers\simplifiers.lib ast\converters\converters.lib model\model.lib ast\macros\macros.lib ast\proofs\proofs.lib ast\substitution\substitution.lib ast\normal_forms\normal_forms.lib ast\rewriter\bit_blaster\bit_blaster.lib ast\rewriter\rewriter.lib math\lp\lp.lib nlsat\nlsat.lib sat\sat.lib math\grobner\grobner.lib ast\euf\euf.lib parsers\util\parser_util.lib smt\params\smt_params.lib ast\ast.lib math\subpaving\subpaving.lib math\realclosure\realclosure.lib params\params.lib math\automata\automata.lib math\hilbert\hilbert.lib math\simplex\simplex.lib math\dd\dd.lib math\interval\interval.lib math\polynomial\polynomial.lib util\util.lib /link /profile /MACHINE:X64 /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /STACK:8388608
shell\datalog_frontend.obj : fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'x86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: “"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.EXE"”: return code “0x2”
```

How to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the commandline, 83 files are to be linked to get a resulting executable:

```
shell\datalog_frontend.obj 
shell\dimacs_frontend.obj 
shell\drat_frontend.obj 
shell\gparams_register_modules.obj 
shell\install_tactic.obj 
shell\main.obj 
...
math\dd\dd.lib
math\interval\interval.lib
math\polynomial\polynomial.lib
util\util.lib
```

I would check three things:

1. Was `shell\datalog_frontend.obj` actually compiled for CPUs with 64
   bits?
   Make sure that all object files and all libraries are compiled for
   the same CPU bit-width.
2. Is it correct that all these files are `.lib` library files rather than `.obj` files?
   They should probably be `.obj` files.
3. Have you seen [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17252770/1911064)? And [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75748805/datalog-frontend-cpp-src-shell-datalog-frontend-cpp20-fatal-error-c1083-c)?

> It is not necessary to build *Z3* on your own. You can just download [precompiled binaries](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/releases).

Comment: Thank you for your answer!    1. Sorry, I don't know how to check whether it's compiled for CPUs with 64 bits.    2.Some of the [tag:.lib]files are [tag:.lib]library files, and names of these files are [tag:xxx.lib] rather than [tag:xxx], which means they should be [tag:xxx.lib.lib] but not [tag:xxx.lib] that shown to me. Other [tag:.lib] files are [tag:.obj]files. All the file names related to [tag:.lib] seem to be wrong file names, and I don't know how to deal with it.

Comment: 3. I have seen [the first link you post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17249072/z3-build-error-using-visual-studio-compilers/17252770#17252770) and tried to built Z3 under 32bits, then I got more than 2000 lines errors (mainly error LNK2019 and error LNK2001).
For the second post, I conducted the same commands as that person, and the errors we meet are different. Is my compiler installation problematic or not correctly installed/configured?

Comment: I won't work on the source code of Z3. I just want to use it as a SMT solver, so can I simply get a binary release without building it?